# Pythonic way to check a dict has all the keys it should

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have some working code but wondered if there is a more pythonic way to code it.

**Working code**

```
mydict = {"a":77, "b":22}
wanted_dict_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

# is each item of the wanted_dict_key present as a key in the dict
def all_keys_present(wanted_dict_keys, mydict):
    existing_keys = []
    keys_missing = []
    for k,v in mydict.items():
        existing_keys.append(k)
    #print(existing_keys)
    for key in wanted_dict_keys:
        if key not in existing_keys:
            keys_missing.append(key)
            #print("this key is not in the dict: ", key)
    return existing_keys, keys_missing

existing_keys, keys_missing = all_keys_present(wanted_dict_keys, mydict)
print('\n')
print("existing_keys : ", existing_keys)
print("keys_missing : ", keys_missing)
```

Comment: Hint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `set` arithmetic following way

```
mydict = {"a":77, "b":22}
wanted_dict_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
missing = set(wanted_dict_keys).difference(mydict.keys())
print(missing)
```

output:

```
{'c'}
```

You might use such created `missing` in if statement, as empty set is considered `False` and all other `True`.

Answer (score 2):

`mydict.keys()` will give you all keys. And `set` will do the equality check.

```py
mydict = {"a":77, "b":22}
wanted_dict_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

if (set(mydict.keys()) == set(wanted_dict_keys)):
    print('all are present')
else:
    print('not all are present')
```

```
not all are present
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `all`:

```py
mydict = {"a":77, "b":22}
wanted_dict_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

if all(k in mydict for k in wanted_dict_keys):
    print("All there")
else:
    raise ValueError("Missing keys!")
```

Or if you want to be specific:

```py
not_present = [k for k in wanted_dict_keys if k not in mydict]

if not_present:
    raise ValueError(f"Missing required keys {not_present}")
else:
    print(f"Got keys: {list(mydict)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

✅ Inline solution: to get both the `existing_keys` and `missing_keys`:

```
existing_keys = [k for k in wanted_dict_keys if k in mydict.keys()]
missing_keys  = [k for k in wanted_dict_keys if k not in mydict.keys()]
```

---

However, if you want to keep the same code structure:

```
mydict = {"a":77, "b":22}
wanted_dict_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

def all_keys_present(wanted_dict_keys, mydict):    
    existing_keys = [k for k in wanted_dict_keys if k in mydict.keys()]
    missing_keys  = [k for k in wanted_dict_keys if k not in mydict.keys()]
    return existing_keys, missing_keys

existing_keys, missing_keys = all_keys_present(wanted_dict_keys, mydict)
print('\n')
print("existing_keys : ", existing_keys)
print("missing_keys  : ", missing_keys)
```

Comment: You don't need the `.keys()` call, simply `if k [not] in mydict` works for membership testing

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to have more keys, then you can use the issubset() function after turning your list of keys into a set.

```
if set(wanted_dict_keys).issubset(mydict):
    print("all keys are present")
else:
    print("some keys are missing")
```

If you want to avoid the set conversion on every check, you should store your `wanted_dict_keys` as a set instead of a list.